# Codeigniter Form Validation Doesn't Work and display Error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have used jQuery datatable for my project.when i add the form validation it display error called "the page at localhost says Error adding/update data. when i run the code without form validations it works fine.i couldn't understand what is the issue with my code.

**Controller**

```
class User_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model','user_controller');
               $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->view('admin_include/header');
        $this->load->view('admin_pages/user_view');
    }

    public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->user_controller->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $person) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $person->firstname;
            $row[] = $person->lastname;
            $row[] = $person->gender;
            $row[] = $person->address;
            $row[] = $person->contact_no;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void()" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$person->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void()" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$person->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->user_controller->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->user_controller->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    public function ajax_edit($id)
    {
        $data = $this->user_controller->get_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function ajax_add()
    {
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_no', 'Contact Number', 'required|numeric|max_length[10]|min_length[10]');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
               echo'<div class="alert alert-danger">'.validation_errors().'</div>';
               exit;
            }
            else{  

        $data = array(
                'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
            );
        $insert = $this->user_controller->save($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }
        }
    public function ajax_update()
    {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_no', 'Contact Number', 'required|numeric|max_length[10]|min_length[10]');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
               echo'<div class="alert alert-danger">'.validation_errors().'</div>';
               exit;
            }else{

        $data = array(
                'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'dob' => $this->input->post('contact_no'),
            );
        $this->user_controller->update(array('id' => $this->input->post('id')), $data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }
}
    public function ajax_delete($id)
    {
        $this->user_controller->delete_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

}
```

**model**

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'user';
    var $column = array('firstname','lastname','gender','address','contact_no');
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc');

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column as $item) 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value'])
                ($i===0) ? $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']) : $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            $column[$i] = $item;
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order']))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();
    }

    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($where, $data)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function delete_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }


}
```

**view**

```
 <h3>Client Data</h3>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="add_person()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Person</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Contact No</th>
          <th style="width:125px;">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Date of Birth</th>
          <th>Contact No</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')?>"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

    var save_method; //for save method string
    var table;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      table = $('#table').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('user_controller/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
          "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
          "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

      });
    });

    function add_person()
    {
      save_method = 'add';
      $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
      $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
      $('.modal-title').text('Add Person'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
    }

    function edit_person(id)
    {
        alert(id);
      save_method = 'update';
      $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

      //Ajax Load data from ajax
      $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('user_controller/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
            $('[name="firstname"]').val(data.firstname);
            $('[name="lastname"]').val(data.lastname);
            $('[name="gender"]').val(data.gender);
            $('[name="address"]').val(data.address);
            $('[name="contact_no"]').val(data.contact_no);

            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit Person'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
    }

    function reload_table()
    {
      table.ajax.reload(null,false); //reload datatable ajax 
    }

    function save()
    {
      var url;
      if(save_method == 'add') 
      {
          url = "<?php echo site_url('user_controller/ajax_add')?>";
      }
      else
      {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('user_controller/ajax_update')?>";
      }

       // ajax adding data to database
          $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {
               //if success close modal and reload ajax table
               $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
               reload_table();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
            }
        });
    }

    function delete_person(id)
    {
      if(confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
      {
        // ajax delete data to database
          $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('user_controller/ajax_delete')?>/"+id,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {
               //if success reload ajax table
               $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
               reload_table();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
            }
        });

      }
    }

  </script>

  <!-- Bootstrap modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Person Form</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body form">
        <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
          <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> 
          <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text" >
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3">Gender</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <select name="gender" class="form-control">
                  <option value="male">Male</option>
                  <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3">Address</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"class="form-control"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3">Date of Birth</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="dob" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Please narrow down your code to only the code relevant to the problem. We don't need to see your whole app. Also ajax is expecting json but your php is outputing html in some instances

Comment: ok.thnx for ur advice

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer HTML 5 validation because it`s very easy way and HTML 5 validation will check on client side or it will check without refresh the page and codeigniter form validation will refresh the page then show then show error so it`s a long way...so please use HTML 5 validation